# Why is this simple list element adder not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I am an amateur programmer working on a basic console game via JavaScript and HTML.

Basically, I am using a text input field to type in text, and when I hit enter, the text gets added as a list element. I'm not sure why my code isn't working, but I do know that the current JS code is causing the rest of my JS to fail. Any help is welcome.
 UPDATE: I get this error from the console:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of nullscript.js:1 (anonymous function)
Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="res/icon.png"/>
                <script src ="script.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="cmd">
                <input id="text_input" placeholder="Type a Command">
            </div>
            <div id="console">
                <ul id="consolelog"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
    document.getElementById('text_input').addEventListener('keypress', function (event){
    if(event.which != 13){
        return;
    }
    else{
        var comment = document.createElement('li');
        comment.textContent = document.getElementById('text_input').value;
        document.getElementById('consolelog').appendChild(comment);
        document.getElementById('text_input').value = "";
    }
}); //a brace was missing here
alert("test");
```

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPKLOZ

Comment: Check out [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/layupipame/1/edit); it will tell you why it doesn't work, i.e. parse error.

Comment: Thanks, I went through each error, yet it still doesn't work.

Comment: Then update your question with the code you've changed it into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is just a missing a brace to close the function you're passing to `.addEventListener`:

```
document.getElementById('text_input').addEventListener('keypress', function (event){
    if(event.which != 13){
        return;
    }
    else{
        var comment = document.createElement('li');
        comment.textContent = document.getElementById('text_input').value;
        var data = document.getElementById('text_input').value
        document.getElementById('consolelog').appendChild(comment);
        document.getElementById('text_input').value = "";
    }
}); //a brace was missing here
alert("test");
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it still isnt working, despite even adding the semicolon. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you added the brace too?

Comment: It works here. Just following your codepen link and pasting the new code in place of the old one works for me.

Comment: thats odd, because it works on codepen, but not on the actual file

Comment: i get this error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of nullscript.js:1 (anonymous function)

Comment: nvm, got it to work, i just needed to put the script tag after the HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('text_input').addEventListener('keypress', function (event){
if(event.which != 13){
    return;
}
else{
    var comment = document.createElement('li');
    comment.textContent = document.getElementById('text_input').value;
    var data = document.getElementById('text_input').value
    document.getElementById('consolelog').appendChild(comment);
    document.getElementById('text_input').value = "";
}
});
alert("test");
```

I have tried this code on the provided codepen link(http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPKLOZ) and found that it is working.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't join this same success